# Should Ember.CollectionView's respect layoutName?

Tags: ember.js

Edit: Question rescinded.  CollectionViews, as a subclass of ContentViews, do not respect layout, frustrating as that is.

CollectionViews don't seem to work with layouts.  For example:

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/73sWp/

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="layoutTest">
    <div class="my-collection">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        {{yield}}
    </div>
</script>       

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="layoutTest-child">
    <div class="an-item">
        Hi there.
    </div>
</script>
```

Script:

```
var TestView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    layoutName: "layoutTest",
    title: "My Collection",
    childViews: [
        Ember.View.create({
            templateName: 'layoutTest-child'
        }),
        Ember.View.create({
            templateName: 'layoutTest-child'
        })
    ]
});
$(function () {
    TestView.create().appendTo(document.body);
});
```

Expected:

```
<div class="my-collection">
    <h1>My Collection</h1>
    <div class="an-item">
        Hi there.
    </div>
    <div class="an-item">
        Hi there.
    </div>
</div>
```

Actual:

```
<div class="an-item">
    Hi there.
</div>
<div class="an-item">
    Hi there.
</div>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

Layouts are template based and CollectionViews have been intended to be used without templates.

This issue has been discussed a bit and I think the consensus is that we'd like to support using layouts with ContainerViews.

A pull request has been submitted that adds this functionality: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/928